# ResolveRequestCache state takes much time

Tags: performance, iis, caching

I have a C# MVC application hosted in IIS test environment with only one action method in APIController. Clients call this single method and depending upon the parameters different small processes are performed.
I am using IIS 10.0.17763. Application is built in .Net Framework 4.6 
I have disabled these modules as i don't need them.
**WebDAVModule

WindowsAuthentication

ScriptModule-4.0

DefaultAuthentication

ServiceModel-4.0

UrlAuthorization

FileAuthorization**

The problem is that under load test from jmeter, all calls somehow stay longer in **ResolveRequestCache** State.
Can someone guide me the problem behind or suggest me something to check. I am not using any kind of caching due to business requirement.

Here is the [Screenshot of requests states from IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFcgi.png)

Edit. I have removed some other modules too to check the effect.
Here is [the list of loaded modules in my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh3CJ.png)

Comment: If you have not disabled these modules, does ResolveRequestCache State also take much time? And do you have complicated code in resolverequestcache event?

Comment: I disabled some other modules too. I am editing the post adding the modules list which are currently loaded in pool. And i have not written any module which is working inside ResolveRequestCache state.

Comment: If i have not disabled these modules then the time is taken inside other modules which i have disabled. For example some event in FileAuthorization Module was taking time and i removed it. Then some other module's (which i don't remember exactly) event was taking much time and i removed that too.

Comment: How many concurrent requests in the iis? and you can also try to use the Debug Diagnostic Tool to grab demp to further analyze the cause of the problem.